# Custom ValidationAttribute in PartialView not showing error messages

Tags: partial-views, asp.net-mvc-5, custom-validators, validationattribute

I did a prof of concept of a custom validation usign ValidationAttribute in an mVC simple site, validating a date range. Only interested in that finishDate was before startDate. And everything worked fine. Well, I have no client validation but the server side works smooth. so far so good.

My problem now is that in my real solution, I have the form as a partial view. the scneario is a resume form where you can create multiple job experiences. I include the _CreatejobExperience partialView in  parent iew and show it with bpopup jquery plugin.

I implemented everything in te same way I did with my smple proof of concept that was working. but when there is a failure in the validation, yet the popup is not closed, the error message does not show.

My validation class is

```
public class DateRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string[] PropertyNames { get; set; }

    public DateRangeAttribute(params string[] propertyNames)
    {
        this.PropertyNames = propertyNames;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var properties = this.PropertyNames.Select(validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty);
        var values = properties.Select(p => p.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null)).OfType<DateTime>();

        var startDate = values.FirstOrDefault();
        var finishDate = (DateTime)value;

        if (finishDate <= startDate)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("La fecha final debe ser posterior ala fecha de inicio");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The properties and decorater is set like this

```
    [Display(Name = "Entry date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Finish date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Required]
    [DateRange("EntryDate", ErrorMessage="Error message")]
    public DateTime RetirementDate { get; set; }
```

And in my controller I have the action that runs on the form post like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult AddJobExperience(JobExperienceViewModel jobExperience)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var resume = (ResumeViewModel)Session["tempResume"];
            resume.JobExperienceViewModels.Add(jobExperience);
            Session["tempResume"] = resume;
            return PartialView("_ListJobExperience", resume.JobExperienceViewModels);
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView("_CreateJobExperience");
        }

    }
```

In my proof of concept, in my controller I have something like,

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Index(ValidationModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsVaid)
    {
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
         return View();
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in the return. how can I make the error message to be shown in the partial view.

**UPDATE**

The Parent View is the Index view of the controller and looks a bit like this. I just removed non relevant parts

```
@using CAEWebSite.Models
@model CAEWebSite.Models.ResumeViewModel

@{ 
ViewBag.Title = "Hoja de Vida";
}

<div class="row">



@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", null, null, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


        <h4>
            @{var fullName = Model.FirstName +
          (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.MiddleName) ? " " + Model.MiddleName : String.Empty) +
          (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.LastName) ? " " + Model.LastName : String.Empty) +
          (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.SecondLastName) ? " " + Model.SecondLastName : String.Empty);
            }
            @fullName
        </h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Model.Email
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Model.UserName
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <h4>Job experiences</h4>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="divListJobExperience">
                @Html.Partial("_ListJobExperience", Model.JobExperienceViewModels)
            </div>
            <p>
                <a href="#" onclick="$('#newJobExperience').bPopup(); return false;">Nueva experiencia</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    }

<div id="newJobExperience" style="background-color:#fff; border-radius:5px;width:60%;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.Partial("_CreateJobExperience", new JobExperienceViewModel())
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Volver a la Lista", "Index", "SearchClient")
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show the parent view too. Is the parent and partial view using the same ViewModel?

Comment: I just added the code you asked, thanks

Comment: I have jquery.unobtrusive included as well in the include script section, but I forgot to add it here